# Is This Singleton Declaration Incorrect?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I'm trying to diagnose a potential thread-safety issue found in my program, and have some suspicions that a singleton object written to provide data is not initialized correctly. The object's initialization is as follows:

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static readonly Singleton Instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

The code that wants to request data from the instance would directly access `Instance`. Which is not in-line with basically every piece of sample singleton code I see, where a getter is used to access a private static `instance`. Could this be causing thready-safety issues in my program?

Comment: Jon Skeet has a write up about the [Singleton Pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) you might find useful.

Comment: sure this  is not a thread safe singleton you can try to take a look to lazy<T> class

Comment: This looks thread-safe to me. The only downside I see with this approach is performance (as the field will be initialized whenever **anything** on the static side is called). I personally think you should be fine with this if performance is not a concern.

Comment: It's *thread safe* but *not lazy*: the instance can be created even if you don't call `Singleton` members at all (so called BeforeFieldInit class)

Comment: Also, Singleton should be sealed.